# use static files in aspnet core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

to state, I am limited with dotnet core 2, that cant change

I am trying to serve some static html page at the base of the wwwroot folder in a basic dotnet core web application but in web browsers, tested chrome and edge, they attempt to download html file as a file to be viewed in a folder.

program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace StudentCookingWebsite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseWebRoot("public")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace StudentCookingWebsite
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

        app.UseStaticFiles();


        }
    }
}
```

could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: That's not how ASP.NET Core works, any edition. Post a reproducible example - actual, minimal code files, the contents of `wwwroot`, file names etc. What you posted is *not* what `dotnet new` produces. It's obviously been modified. There may be other modifications that prevent your application from working too

Comment: From Atahan Ceylan: `For asp.net core it seems OK. Can you show html file?Maybe html file is corrupted. Also can you clear Chrome cache and try again? https://gundersen.net/chrome-downloading-file-instead-of-displaying-page-solved/`

Comment: What's the file name and how did you try to access it? ASP.NET Core doesn't specify any default documents, you'll have to [call UseDefaultFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-a-default-document) before `UseStaticFiles()`.